# using constant memory prints address instead of value in cuda

Tags: cuda, gpu-constant-memory

I am trying to use the constant memory in the code with constant memory assigned value from kernel not using cudacopytosymbol.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #define N 10
    //__constant__ int constBuf_d[N];
    __constant__ int *constBuf;

__global__ void foo( int *results )
{
    int tdx = threadIdx.x;
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + tdx;


    if( idx < N )
    {
        constBuf[idx]=1;
         results[idx] = constBuf[idx];
    }
}

// main routine that executes on the host
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *results_h = new int[N];
    int *results_d;


    cudaMalloc((void **)&results_d, N*sizeof(int));

    foo <<< 1, 10 >>> ( results_d );

    cudaMemcpy(results_h, results_d, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for( int i=0; i < N; ++i )
        printf("%i ", results_h[i] );
        delete(results_h);
}
```

output shows

```
6231808 6226116 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want the program to print the value assigned to constant memory through the kenel in the code.

Comment: As the name implies, `__constant__` memory is *constant*. It can't be changed by a kernel. So (leaving aside the use of an unintialised pointer) what you are trying to do can **never** work.

Comment: is it always necessary to declare host array or data and copy host data to constant memory in device as int arr[10] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12, 3, 5, 3, 6, 6 };
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constBuf, arr, N*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant memory is, as the name implies, constant/read-only with respect to device code. What you are trying to do is illegal and can't be made to work.

To set values in constant memory, you currently have two choices:

1. set the value from host code via the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` API call (or its equivalents)
2. use static initialisation at compile time

In the latter case something like this would work:

```
__constant__ int constBuf[N] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12, 3, 5, 3, 6, 6 };

__global__ void foo( int *results )
{
    int tdx = threadIdx.x;
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + tdx;


    if( tdx < N )
    {
        results[idx] = constBuf[tdx]; // Note changes here!
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i use constant pointer in this example as  __constant__ int *constBuf

Comment: @user3545251: you can't. Constant memory objects must be statically defined at compilation time. If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it so as to get this question off the unanswered list and make it more visible in search for the next person that comes along with a similar question.

Comment: i have a constant structure as struct CDistance
{
 int Magnitude;
 int Direction;
}; and constant as __constant__ CDistance *c_daSTLDistance; and in the kernel I have __global__ static void  CalcSTLDistance_Kernel(CDistance *m_daSTLDistance,int ComputeParticleNumber)
{
 int ID = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
 CDistance NearestDistance;
 int NearestID = -1;
 NearestDistance.Magnitude = 1e8;
 
 c_daSTLDistance[ID] = NearestDistance} but it doesnot show memory write error through cuda-memcheck but shows error in memory read operation in this kernal .

Comment: @user3545251: Defining a pointer in constant memory doesn't do what you think it does. Only the value of the pointer (ie the address of the memory it points to) is being stored in constant memory.

Comment: Is there a possibilty of read error is due to use of pointer in kernel. can excessive use of if else conditional check inside kernel causes such unknown error???